# Inherit attribute value through multiple recursive templates in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Let's say I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<a id="x">
    <b>
        <b>
            <a id="y">
                <b>
                    <c />
                </b>
            </a>
        </b>
        <c>
            <a id="z">
                <b>
                    <c />
                </b>
            </a>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

After many hours of working, I've finally gotten it so that the "a", "b", and "c" templates recurse properly. The one probably I have left is that I need the value of `a/@id` to be available in `b` and `c`. But I also need to be able to reset that value when it gets to the inner `a`. (That is, in `a#x > b > b > a#y > b > c` I need the value 'y', but in `a#x > b > b` I need the value 'x'. In other words, I need the most ancestorally-recent value of `a/@id`.)

The problem is complicated by the fact that the `b` elements can be nested an indeterminate number of times, so it's not simply the case of doing `../../@id` or something.

Since it doesn't seem like variables or parameters would work for this, I was thinking an acceptable workaround would be to automatically carry the `@id` down to each child element. However, I couldn't figure out a way to do this using `xsl:attribute`, as that always seems to modify the output tree, rather than the input or currently-processing tree.

Any tips?

Comment: You haven't said what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do `ancestor::a[first()]/@id`?

```
<xsl:template match="a">
   ...
   <xsl:apply-templates match="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
   <xsl:variable name="id" select="ancestor::a[first()]/@id" />
   ...
   <xsl:apply-templates match="*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
   <xsl:variable name="id" select="ancestor::a[first()]/@id" />
   ...
   <xsl:apply-templates match="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It's actually `ancestor::a[1]/@id`, but yes, thank you! I've been staring at this for so long I couldn't remember what I'd tried and what I hadn't.

Comment: @GPHemsley: Oops. I couldn't remember off the top of my head what the attribute syntax was. Fixed now.